# Split string by multiple delimiters

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to split a string by whitespaces, `,` and `'` using a single ruby command.

1. `word.split` will split by white spaces;
2. `word.split(",")` will split by `,`;
3. `word.split("\'")` will split by `'`.

How to do all three at once?

Comment: Karan, you've probably noticed you don't have to escape the single quote as long as it's between double quotes.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

```
word = "Now is the,time for'all good people"
word.split(/[\s,']/)
 => ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "people"]
```

Comment: Hey, people, thanks for all the upvotes over the past two years, but please don't overlook @oldergod's answer.

Answer (score 66):

Regex.

```
"a,b'c d".split /\s|'|,/
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: I missed your answer earlier.  I prefer it to mine because it reads better (the use of 'or').  You forgot to include `|\s`, probably because you misread the question.

Answer (score 39):

You can use a combination of the `split` method and the [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) method like so:

```
delimiters = [',', ' ', "'"]
word.split(Regexp.union(delimiters))
# => ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "people"]
```

You can even use regex patters in the delimiters.

```
delimiters = [',', /\s/, "'"]
word.split(Regexp.union(delimiters))
# => ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "people"]
```

This solution has the advantage of allowing totally dynamic delimiters or any length.

Comment: Hell yeah buddy! Thanks. This is the best solution so far, imo.

Comment: This is the most readable for other devs who aren't as familiar with Regex. 

Comment: Not as concise, but easy on tired eyes.

Answer (score 25):

Here is another one  :

```
word = "Now is the,time for'all good people"
word.scan(/\w+/)
# => ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "people"]
```

> `\w+` in Ruby regex matches one or more alphanumeric characters. It works by finding the first alphanumeric character, then checking the next character. If the next character is alphanumeric, it's included in the match. This process repeats until a non-alphanumeric character is found.

Comment: This is very very clean, for some common circumstances. Can you just add a note as to what `w+` does in REGEX please? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaPinter _`\w+` in Ruby regex matches one or more alphanumeric characters. It works by finding the first alphanumeric character, then checking the next character. If the next character is alphanumeric, it's included in the match. This process repeats until a non-alphanumeric character is found._

Comment: Thanks! I've added it to your answer for easy reference.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = "one,two, three four" 

new_array = x.gsub(/,|'/, " ").split
```

Comment: I like your approach to it and yes it gives the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I just happened to stumble on it and thought I would leave another answer.  I personally like to avoid using `regex`, both because I find it hard to read and because its almost always slower than using other built in methods.  So, instead of the aforementioned regex solutions, I would also consider using the following:

```
word.gsub(",", " ").gsub("'", " ").split
```

The first `gsub` replaces all occurrences of `,` with a `space`.  The second gsub replaces all occurrences of `'` with a `space`.  This results in `whitespace` at all the desired locations.  And then `split` with no argument simply splits on whitespace.

Its only slightly faster than some of the aforementioned solutions, but I do believe it is faster than any others that have been mentioned.