# Split a string by two delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split a string by whitespaces and # using a single ruby command.

```
word.split(" ") will split by whitespaces ;

word.split("#") will split by '.
```

How to do all three at once?

Comment: This question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509307/split-string-by-multiple-delimiters/19509391#19509391).

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions' [character class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) to do that:

```
word.split(/[ #]/)
```

To match any whitespace character use `\s` : `word.split(/[\s#]/)`

> A character class is delimited with square brackets ([, ]) and lists
>   characters that may appear at that point in the match. /[ab]/ means a
>   or b, as opposed to /ab/ which means a followed by b.
>
> /\s/ - A whitespace character: /[ \t\r\n\f]/

Comment: Thank you that what i was looking for actually